# Spring data mongodb check inside array whether value presents

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to fetch all documents in which readBy array has suppose "2" value using spring data API.
Please help me.

My JSON in Mongodb is like this.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52c14eb92f7ceb854e445354"),
  "attachments" : [{
      "fileMongoId" : "52c14eb82f7ceb854e44534b",
      "fileName" : "Desert.jpg",
      "fileSize" : "0 MB",
      "fileType" : "image/jpeg"
    }, {
      "fileMongoId" : "52c14eb82f7ceb854e445350",
      "fileName" : "Hydrangeas.jpg",
      "fileSize" : "0 MB",
      "fileType" : "image/jpeg"
    }],
  "from" : NumberLong(2),
  "fromName" : "xyz",
  "hasAttachment" : true,
  "message" : "Hi all\r\n",
  "read" : 1,
  "readBy" : ["2", "3"],
  "sentTime" : NumberLong("1388400312645"),
  "sentType" : 2,
  "subject" : "Hi",
  "to" : [{
      "toId" : "3",
      "toName" : "pqr"
    }, {
      "toId" : "2",
      "toName" : "xyz"
    }]
}
```

Code to generate query
Username is string which I want to check whether it is present in readBy array or not
readBy is array of String

```
Query query = new Query();
        Update update = new Update();

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        if (read) {

            // criteria = Criteria.where(username).in("readBy");
            query.addCriteria(criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("to.toId")
                    .in(toIdList)));
        } else {
            // criteria = Criteria.where(username).nin("readBy");
            update.addToSet("readBy", username);
            query.addCriteria(criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("to.toId")
                    .in(toIdList)));
            mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, NewMessage.class);
        }
        query.fields().include("from");
        query.fields().include("fromName");
        query.fields().include("sentTime");
        query.fields().include("hasAttachment");
        query.sort().on("sentTime", Order.DESCENDING);

        newMessages = mongoTemplate.find(query, NewMessage.class);
```

Comment: It is better if you put the code that you are using now to write the query

Comment: you want where("readBy").is(username) to check if username is in readBy array.  But shouldn't you actually be querying for the opposite? where username is *not* in readBy array?